# Build directory for Qt Creator IDE

Tags: qt, build, directory, qt5, qt-creator

I am trying to populate a `QTableview` with some data. When developing under Qt Creator, data is read from build directory. Running the program each time, the `QTableview` keeps getting repopulated with previous data.

If I manually change the build directory each time before run, doesn't happen. But how do I solve the problem without manually changing the build directory every time I want a fresh run?

Comment: Qannie  What is your IDE ? Qt creator ? Visual studio?

Comment: Qt creator is my IDE

Comment: I cannot see the link with QTableView, though.

Comment: At least I don't understand your question. What does build directory have to do with (re?)populating a `QTableView` (I presume you mean repopulating a `QStandardItemModel` or something, more precisley?). How do you populate it?

Comment: Do you mean, you save data in the build directory, and then you want it gone before every build? Add a custom command to the build (under Projects tab), which deletes the saved data files.

Comment: @hyde Yes what you described is my exact issue. Could you elaborate on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory there is a file name `ProjectName.pro.user`.

This file creating when you configure your project. it's [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file.

you can find this line on `*.user` files:

```
<value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.BuildConfiguration.BuildDirectory">C:/Users/probook/Documents/Qt/testProject/Build/Windows/Debug</value>
```

This line define build directory address for debug. there is a same line for Release and Profile in that file.

You can also use Qt creator to define(customize) relative directory build:
goto Qt creator, `Tools`, `Options...`, `Build & Run`, `General`, `Default build directory`. 
[image: Screenshot]

More info:

[Qt Creator stores user-specific project settings in a .pro.user file. You can share these settings between several projects as a .pro.shared file. It has the same XML structure as a .pro.user file, but only contains the settings to share.](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-sharing-project-settings.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info! But do know any other solution to avoid repopulating data in qtableview instead of changing the build directory?

Comment: @annie Can you explaine more about your project?  Is it possible to clear QTableView on startup ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment, issue seems to be data which gets saved to build directory. And solution would be to remove it before running the application.

You can add *Custom Process Step*, either under *Projects - Build Settings -
 Build Steps*, or under *Projects - Run Settings - Deployment*, and just delete the desired data files. Exact command depends on operating system.

An alternative might be to add a command line switch, something like `--development-erase-saved-data`, to the application itself, and erase the files (or just not read them, or whatever). Then add that command line switch to *Projects - Run Settings - Run Steps - Command Line Arguments* for desired build configurations.

Adding support for this in the application itself is easier to maintain, and is almost automatically cross-platform. However, it might be a feature you don't want in the application, though in that case you might only enable it for Debug builds (with `#ifdef`).

---

As a side note, saving data to executable directory is not a good idea these days. You might want to save it for example to location returned by

`QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)`

(See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) for more info.)